# Write a script that shows the following picture exactly as shown below

Tags: shell, scripting

Write a script that shows the following picture exactly as shown below

```
|￣￣￣￣￣￣￣ |  
|    Pizza                |
|＿＿＿＿＿ _＿_|
(\__/) || 
( - | -) || 
/ 　  \
```

Comment: Welcome to SE U&L.  Please take the time to view the help centers guide on [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: I'm voting to close this order as off-topic because this is not a script-writing service.

Comment: You might be looking for [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo '|￣￣￣￣￣￣￣ |  
|    Pizza                |
|＿＿＿＿＿ _＿_|
(\__/) || 
( - | -) || 
/ 　  \  '
```